# Want to use multiple |window on a single stream with kapacitor

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

**Goal:** I would like a notification 5 minutes after an alert condition and then every 30 minutes thereafter.

I played around with [.count()](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.0/tick/expr/) and the [time](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.0/tick/expr/) function but that went nowhere, I didn't want to have to calculate that mess out and I couldn't figure out a way to make it user friendly and reliable.

The solution I am working with now is to have two streams with separate windows.

```
var initialData = stream
        |from()
            .database(db)
            .measurement(metricType)
            .retentionPolicy(rPolicy)
            .groupBy(group)
            .where(lambda: "cpu" == 'cpu-total')
            .where(lambda: "host" =~ hostFilter)
        |mean(metric)
            .as('initialStat')
        |window()
            .period(10m)
            .every(5m)
            .align()

var continuousData = stream
    |from()
        .database(db)
        .measurement(metricType)
        .retentionPolicy(rPolicy)
        .groupBy(group)
        .where(lambda: metricType == 'cpu-total')
        .where(lambda: "host" =~ hostFilter)
    |mean(metric)
        .as('continuousStat')
    |window()
        .period(10m)
        .every(30)
        .align()
```

Beyond the fact this just seems odd, I would then need to calculate out the values for each and I also need separate `|alert()` nodes. The first node will only notify on state change, but the second node can't have this so I get an alert reminder every N minutes. I also have the problem that the first `|alert()` node will send out the `OK` notification and the second will also send out a dupe `OK` N minutes later.

I feel there has to be a better way of doing this. I am thinking I may be able to use an `if` statement in the second `|alert()` node to not send out a notification on `OK` as the first `|window` will handle that. At this point I haven't yet figured out how to even do this but I am sure it is possible. I also don't want to fight tickscript, I know it is not designed to be a full blown language per [Issue 741](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/741)

The full tickscript is below

```
// CONFIGURATION PARAMETERS

// Alerting

var emailAddress = '$EMAIL'
var pagerdutyKey = '$PD'
var slackChannel = '$SLACK'

// Static Thresholds in percent cpu steal used
var warn = 85
var crit = 95

// Dynamic thresholds in number of std deviations
var warnSig = 2.5
var critSig = 3.5

// Print INFO level (every result will be an alert)
// AlertNode.StateChangesOnly will also need to be disabled
// NOTE:
// INFO level alerts will be disregarded by the pagerduty handler, this is not configurable.
var debug = FALSE

// Datastream
// Define the data that will be acted upon
var db           = 'telegraf'
var group        = 'host'
var metricType   = 'cpu'
var metric       = 'time_steal'
var rPolicy      = 'default'

// Regex used to filter on a subset of hosts
var hostFilter = /.+/

// Window
var dataPeriod            = 10m
var initialFrequency      = 5m
var continuousFrequency   = 30m

// DATAFRAME
var initialData = stream
    |from()
        .database(db)
        .measurement(metricType)
        .retentionPolicy(rPolicy)
        .groupBy(group)
        .where(lambda: metricType == 'cpu-total')
        .where(lambda: "host" =~ hostFilter)
    |mean(metric)
        .as('initialStat')
    |window()
        .period(dataPeriod)
        .every(initialFrequency)
        .align()

var continuousData = stream
    |from()
        .database(db)
        .measurement(metricType)
        .retentionPolicy(rPolicy)
        .groupBy(group)
        .where(lambda: metricType == 'cpu-total')
        .where(lambda: "host" =~ hostFilter)
    |mean(metric)
        .as('continuousStat')
    |window()
        .period(dataPeriod)
        .every(continuousFrequency)
        .align()

// Calculations
var initialCalculation = initialData
    |eval(lambda: sigma("initialStat"))
        .as('intialSigma')
        .keep()

var continuousCalculation = continuousData
    |eval(lambda: sigma("continuousStat"))
        .as('continuousSigma')
        .keep()

// ALERT CONDITIONS
var initialCondition = initialCalculation
    |alert()
        .id('{{ index .Tags "host"  }}')
        .message('{{ .ID  }} is {{ .Level  }}: CPU STEAL USAGE {{ index .Fields "initialStat" }}% SHORT')
        .details('this is an alert')
        .stateChangesOnly()
        .info(lambda: debug)
        .warn(lambda: "stat" < warn OR
            "sigma" > warnSig)
        .crit(lambda: "stat" < crit OR
            "sigma" > critSig)

var continuousCondition = continuousCalculation
    |alert()
        .id('{{ index .Tags "host"  }}')
        .message('{{ .ID  }} is {{ .Level  }}: CPU STEAL USAGE {{ index .Fields "continuousStat" }}% LONG')
        .details('this is an alert')
        .info(lambda: debug)
        .warn(lambda: "stat" < warn OR
            "sigma" > warnSig)
        .crit(lambda: "stat" < crit OR
            "sigma" > critSig)

// ACTIONS
continuousCondition
        // .log('/tmp/alerts/cpu_steal_usage_alerts')
        // .slack()
        // .channel(slackChannel)
        .email(emailAddress)
        .pagerDuty()
                .serviceKey(pagerdutyKey)

initialCondition
        // .log('/tmp/alerts/cpu_steal_usage_alerts')
        // .slack()
        // .channel(slackChannel)
        .email(emailAddress)
        .pagerDuty()
                .serviceKey(pagerdutyKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I can do multiple windows in a single stream node.

```
stream
    |from()
        .database(db)
        .measurement(metricType)
        .retentionPolicy(rPolicy)
        .groupBy(group)
        .where(lambda: metricType == metricFilter)
        .where(lambda: "host" =~ hostFilter)
    |window()
        .period(dataPeriod)
        .every(initialFrequency)
        .align()
    |mean(metric)
        .as('initialStat')
    |window()
        .period(dataPeriod)
        .every(continuousFrequency)
        .align()
    |mean(metric)
        .as('continuousStat')
```

Still working through the `OK` issue though.